# How to compare values in tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tuples

I am just trying to figure out how I would go about getting a specific value from a tuple in a list of tuples.

For example, say I have a list of tuples:

```
list = [(12345, 6789, 23456), (156748, 347890, 1234556), (1009544, 13578690, 1223455), ....]
```

The list has 128 tuples in it, and the tuples each have three arbitrarily large values.

What I need to do is get the 3rd value from each tuple as I need to use these values for each pair of tuples and find their greatest common divisor.

For example I need to take 23456 from tuple 1 and 1234556 from tuple 2 and find their gcd, then I need to do the same for tuple 2 and 3, etc..

This bit I can do, however I am a little confused on how I would go about getting the third value of each tuple from the list.

I know if it was just a list I could simply just call `list[3*m]` where m is in range 1 to 128.

And get the numbers at all positions of multiples of threes, I could do the same for tuples. But I don't know how to go about doing this for a list of tuples.

Sorry if this is a little confusing. I tried to explain it to the best of my ability.

I'm not asking for code or anything, just an explanation on how I would go about finding a value at a certain position of all tuples in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following approach to get pairs of values to calculate your GCD values:

```
def calc_gcd(v1, v2):
    print v1, v2        # add your GCD code here

list_of_tuples = [(12345, 6789, 23456), (156748, 347890, 1234556), (1009544, 13578690, 1223455), (12345, 6789, 23456)]

for p1, p2 in zip(list_of_tuples[:-1], list_of_tuples[1:]):
    calc_gcd(p1[2], p2[2])
```

This would display the following output:

```
23456 1234556
1234556 1223455
1223455 23456
```

The `calc_gcd` function can then be written to display your desired result. Note, do not use `list` as a variable name as it will shadow Python's own list function.

How does this work? The `zip` function here is taking two lists, and for each iteration of the loop it returns an item from each list. The trick is to give it your list of tuples twice, one starting from the beginning, and the second starting from the second entry, this way you will get consecutive pairs of entries returned.

So `p1` is a tuple and `p2` is a tuple, it then passes the 3rd value from each to the gcd function, note Python starts numbering from 0, so the third entry has an index of 2.

To create a list of the pairs, a Python `list comprehension` can be used to build the list as follows:

```
pairs = [(p1[2], p2[2]) for p1, p2 in zip(list_of_tuples[:-1], list_of_tuples[1:])]

for v1, v2 in pairs:
    calc_gcd(v1, v2)
```

`pairs` would hold:

```
[(23456, 1234556), (1234556, 1223455), (1223455, 23456)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and explanation! :) finally would there be a way I can store these values p1, p2 rather than immediately putting them into my Gcd function. And then using the stored values to find the gcds?

Comment: Certainly, by using a list comprehension to build it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Oh okay thank you, so now my pairs list is another list of tuples. And I can iterate over it to put each tuple of pairs in my Gcd function

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the index to the tuples as with a list:

```
>>> list[0][2]
23456
>>> list[1][2]
1234556
```

See for example a [tutorial about tuples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

Then you can for example loop the list and compare the 3rd item of one tuple with the 3rd item of the second:

```
for i in range(0,len(list),2):
   yourFunction(list[i][2], list[i+1][2])
```

Comment: Okay thank you, but this may be rather long for a list of 128 tuples :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via list comprehension like:

```
x = [(12345, 6789, 23456), (156748, 347890, 1234556), (1009544, 13578690, 1223455)]

[t[2] for t in x]

[23456, 1234556, 1223455]
```

Comment: Hi so would that create a new list with all the values at the second position of each tuple? So could I do my_list = t[2] for t in x

Comment: Yes, if you mean second==third :) (indexes start from 0)

Comment: Hi I tried this with my list, and when I then print the next list created, that list prints 3 or 4 times, so it is adding the values quite a few times to the list, e.g. say i print my_list which is the list you created above, then the output would be [23456, 1234556, 1223455], [23456, 1234556, 1223455]

Comment: I'm not sure what caused the problem for you. In the example, I've tried with the list of triples you provided, and it worked as shown. I should see your code to find out what it did.

Answer (score 1):

You got excellent answers already.
In case you want to calculate the GCDs of the third value in adjacent tuples you could do:

```
import fractions
t = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)]
agg = [iter(t)]*2
gcds = [fractions.gcd(a[2],b[2]) for a,b in zip(*agg)]
print(gcds)
```

produces a list containing

```
[3, 3]
```

which can be read as

```
[GCD(3, 6), GCD(9, 12), ....]
```

Comment: Hi so this produced output [3, 3] would that be the Gcd for just the first and second tuples and the second and third? Also sorry as I am new to python I don't quite understand what the final line is doing, could I possibly bother you for an explanation? And also is this code also creating a list of the third values of each tuple? Thank you for the help

Comment: please see my edit. The final product is a list containing only the GCDs of the third elements of adjacent tuples, for all the tuples provided (in my example case two pairs of tuples)

Answer (score 0):

Like allway when you have a problem according to iteration in Python you can use methods from itertools. In this case combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

def do_something(list_of_tuples):
    for two_tuples in combinations(list_of_tuples, 2):
        """Do whatever you want to do with your values"""
        gcd = your_method_to_calculate_gcd(two_tuples[0][3], two_tuples[1][3])
```

or

```
from itertools import combinations

def do_something(list_of_tuples):
    for t1. t2 in combinations(list_of_tuples, 2):
        """Do whatever you want to do with your values"""
        gcd = your_method_to_calculate_gcd(t1[3], t2[3])
```

`combinations(list_of_tuples, 2)` will give you every unique pair of tuples with (a,b) == (b,a) - use permutations if you want (a, b) != (b,a) - and you can simply compute the gcd for the third elements like you had - because you have - just a list of two tuples.

And don't worry about performance, all itertools methods are higly performant.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
ls = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
lsAns = [i[2] for i in ls]
print max(lsAns)
```

Comment: Sorry just wondering does the final line then print the highest value in the lsAns? And also so this method now creates a new list with just the values I Wanted. So then would it be possible for me to then use this list to compare the values in the list as I would a normal list?

Comment: Yes you can use lsAns as any other normal python list.